# xsd restriction allowing any lowercase or uppercase or numbers

Tags: xsd, schema

I have a following schema accepting only COM1-4.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

    <xs:schema
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      elementFormDefault="qualified">

      <xs:complexType name="Component">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="ComponentType"/>    
      </xs:complexType>

      <xs:simpleType name="ComponentType">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="COM1"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="COM2"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="COM3"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="COM4"/>
            </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
```

Now the requirement has changed. I need to allow any characters(lower or uppercase). I need to make it backward-compatible with the previous values which are already populated in the production env.

I want to preserve 'ComponentType' name and enum types for ComponentType. I would like to minimize the code change. If possible, I would like to take care of it in the schema level. These COM[1-4] is just naming convention changed for this post. Actual values are different.

Is there a way to change the schema which can accept the any characters(lower or uppercase) within the scope of schema without regenerating the java artifacts or make a change on java code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work, but I have no idea on the impact on your Java code:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ComponentType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:pattern value="[cC][oO][mM][1-3]"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but COM is just a name for this post. It's not COM in my actual schema as I mentioned in my question.  I just want to make it accept any lower or uppercase characters in my new schema.